# Reorder Json Object keys in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

For example the following

```
[
    {'1000': '', '5000': '', '10000': '', 'Name': 'test1', 'Email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'Reason': ''},
    {'1000': '', '5000': '', '10000': '', 'Name': 'test2', 'Email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'Reason': ''}
]
```

Is there a way to reorder like:

```
[
    {'Name': 'test1', 'Email': 'test1@gmail.com', '1000': '', '5000': '', '10000': '', 'Reason': ''},
    {'Name': 'test2', 'Email': 'test2@gmail.com', '1000': '', '5000': '', '10000': '', 'Reason': ''}
]
```

Comment: [No, there is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: Your example isn't clear. Will you add a more clear example please?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, the answer is **no**. Although ES6 (along with modern browser standards and implementations) guarantee the order of object properties, there's one major exception: **integer indices**.

Due to your object having keys like `'1000'`, `'5000'`, and `'10000'`, you won't be able to achieve the order you desire; these integer indices will always be first.

> Property keys are traversed in the following order:
>
> - First, the keys that are integer indices in ascending numeric order.
> - Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
>
> [...]
>
> Roughly, an integer index is a string that, if converted to a 53-bit non-negative integer and back is the same value. Therefore:
>
> - `'10'` and `'2'` are integer indices.
> - `'02'` is not an integer index. Coverting it to an integer and back results in the different string `'2'`.
> - `'3.141'` is not an integer index, because `3.141` is not an integer.

([Source](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html))

And a brief example:

```js
const obj = {
  "Z": 1,
  "B": 2,
  "C": 3
};

console.log(obj);   //Maintains creation order

const obj2 = {
  "A": 1,
  "B": 2,
  "100": 3
}

console.log(obj2);  //Does not maintain creation order
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of object properties should not matter. If it does you have a bad design at hand. The best approach is to rethink your design.